# Unable to install realm package

Tags: active-directory, domain, packages, centos6.5

I am trying to join **Centos 6.5 to Active Directory domain** . I have upgraded all the packages using `yum upgrade`. but I'm unable to install realm package, it say 'no package realmd available'. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no package called `realmd` available in the yum repo's that you have configured, as the error quite clearly states.

Background: `realmd` is only included in RHEL/CentOS 7, the closest alternative for RHEL 6 is `adcli`.